# I keep seeing ShortMove on Chess.js tutorials, but it's not there anymore

Tags: reactjs, chess

I'm trying to make a chess game using react. I am using chessboardjsx and chess.js. I am working with an online tutorial:
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-create-a-simple-chess-app-with-react-e18c0179b167
In this, they use ShortMove to handle moves, but it gives me an error when I try to import it because it's not in Chess.js. Maybe I'm doing something stupid but I think it was removed or changed in Chess.js.

Here is an image to show the issue.
[image: Error Image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7Amy.png)

I tried to use Move rather than ShortMove, but Move needs a bunch of properties like color, piece, flag, and sans, which ShortMove doesn't need. Here's the error I get.[image: Move error]

Can someone tell me if there is an alternative or how I can make Move work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ShortMove is a Typescript type, if you are not using Typescript you don't need to worry about that and can remove it.

If you ARE using typescript and they do not show up you should made sure that in addition to installing the Library from with `npm install chess.js` you also installed the types by running:

`npm install -D @types/chess.js`

from the commandline

That command comes from the instalation instructions here:
https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I had to change the import path from just "chess.js" to "../node_modules/@types/chess.js". Now it is working.